# Sharepoint 2010 listdata.svc returns exception Value cannot be null. Parameter name: target. On orderby with lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, web-services, rest

I'm trying to use SharePoint 2010 `ListData.svc` with jqgrid control. It works fine, but when I try to use orderby with lookup field, I get an exception:

> -An error occurred while processing this
>   request.-Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name:
>   targetSystem.ArgumentNullException
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceUtil.GetValue(Object target,
>   ResourceProperty resourceProperty) at lambda_method(ExecutionScope ,
>   DataServiceEntity ) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.<CombineSelectors>b__11(TSource
>   x) at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BasicExpandProvider.ExpandedEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription
>   description, IDataService dataService) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription
>   description) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()

This Exception throws only if target list have items with empty lookup field. Is this correct?

For example - my url: `http://{servName}/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/{ListName}()?$expand=LkTest&$select=Title,LkTest&$orderby=LkTest/Title`

Answer (score 2):

Most probably this error occurs due to `orderby` operator, in particular this error is encountered when lookup value is null(empty) and hence ordering by projected field could not be applied:

```
$orderby=LookupField/ProjectedFieldName  //<- LookupField is null
```

The solution would to apply the filter that *excludes* list items with null lookup values, for example:

```
$filter=LookupField ne null
```

**Complete example**:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName?$expand=LookupField&$select=Title,LookupField&$filter=LookupField ne null&$orderby=LookupField/FieldName
```

Comment: I also thought about the filter, but it will not be entirely correct to exclude from list some items just because they lookup field is not filled. At least a standard interface does not do this. Are there any other ways to solve this problem?